# Perl push a key before a hash data set

Tags: perl, hashmap, hashtable

I managed to create a hash data set with a subroutine,

```
my %check_ip = (
    "data1" => $ip1,
    "data2" => $ip2,
    "data3" => $ip3
    ); 

      'data1' => '127.0.0.1',
      'data2' => '192.168.0.1',
      'data3' => '192.168.1.1'
```

This is a simple hash. 
I am looking to put another key behind this, so that this would become a hash of hash, and look like

```
config1 =>
      'data1' => '127.0.0.1',
      'data2' => '192.168.0.1',
      'data3' => '192.168.1.1',
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You should read and understand [perlreftut - Mark's very short tutorial about references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)/ It is part of the standard Perl 5 release and is very well written

Comment: Thanks Borodin. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a nested hash, you need a hash reference.

```
my %check_ip = (
      data1 => $ip1,
      data2 => $ip2,
      data3 => $ip3,
    );
my %config = ( config1 => \%check_ip );
```

Comment: Thanks Choroba. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $ip1='127.0.0.1';
my $ip2='192.168.0.1';
my $ip3='192.168.1.1';
my %check_ip = (
                 config1 => { "data1" => $ip1,
                              "data2" => $ip2,
                              "data3" => $ip3, },
           );
```

Access like below:

```
print $check_ip{config1}{data1}; #output 127.0.0.1
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/26bchp)

Answer (score 1):

Since a hash key can only have one value, the nested hash needs to be stored as a hash reference, which is what the curly braces `{}` are used for:

```
my %check_ip = (
                 config1 => { "data1" => $ip1,
                              "data2" => $ip2,
                              "data3" => $ip3, },
               );
```

See [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more information on Perl data structures.